# How do I save the related models when I save the parent model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a quiz manager where a user can add questions and edit the answers for those questions. I want to have it to where a user clicks one save button and it saves both the questions and the answers for that question. So my question is how do I access and call the save() from the question save() method. However I get an error: *There is no save method*. Ill try to provide as much as I can but please let me know if you need anything else

**Question Controller**

```
App.QuestionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        softSave: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.get('model').save().then(function() {
                //this is what throws the error        
                self.get('answers').save();
                console.log('%c Question was saved','color:green;');

            }, function() {
                console.log('%c Question not saved', 'color:red;');
            });
        }
    }

});
```

**Question Model**

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
  'quiz': DS.belongsTo('quiz'),
  'text': attr('string'),
  'ord': attr('number'),
  'answers': DS.hasMany('answer' , { async: true } )
});
```

**Answer Model**

```
 App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({
  'question': DS.belongsTo('question'),
  'content': attr('string'),
  'correct_answer': attr('boolean')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `answers` isn't a model; it's an array of models. So, the easiest way to fix would be to do something like:

```
App.QuestionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  softSave: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.get('model').save().then(function() {     
      self.get('answers').forEach(function(answer) { answer.save(); });
    });
  }
});
```